# Significado de parte do código JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Montei um código para impedir que minha ferramenta de busca faça pesquisas com o campo de busca em branco ou com a mensagem padrão que aparece no value, recebi uma parte do código e ao implementar apareceu um erro que antes não ocorria no *layout*, tem uma pequena parte do código que não tenho o conhecimento do que faz e que antes não tinha no código e não aparecia o erro.

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<form name="produtosBuscaForm" method="get" action="http://busca.exemplo.com.br"  onsubmit="return ajaxsearchsubmit(this)">  

        <!--!! <input type="hidden" name="Categoria" value="0" id="categoria"> !!-->
        $&{<input type="hidden" name="view" value="(view)" />}       
                 <div class="busca">
         <div class="inputbusca">
            <input type="text" name="w" maxlength="35" value="Digite a busca" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Digite a busca') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if(value=='') value ='Digite a busca'"id="sli_search_1" autocomplete="off" style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;font-style:italic;font-weight:lighter;font-size:12px;color:#999999;outline:none;">
         </div>
                    <a href="javascript:return ajaxsearchsubmit(document.produtosBuscaForm);" class="ok"></a>
                 </div>                 
    </form>
```

Minha duvida é com relação a seguinte parte:

```
 <!--!! <input type="hidden" name="Categoria" value="0" id="categoria"> !!-->
        $&{<input type="hidden" name="view" value="(view)" />}
```

A parte comentada OK, mas o que seria o comando `$&{    }`? Será que esta parte pode estar me ocasionando o erro?

Comment: Pelo que entendi (conforme descrito [neste blog](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2198-special-references-in-javascript-s-string-replace-method.htm) em inglês), `$&` retorna o último string retornado por uma expressão regular. Neste contexto, não sei se é o que pode estar causando o erro, talvez seja mais fácil determinar se você montar um exemplo no jsFiddle.

Comment: Testa se o input esta vazio ou com o texto padrao, dê algum tipo de alert e um return false. Não é mais facil?

Comment: Qual o erro que aparece? Estou com uma resposta quase pronta para emitir pra você.

Comment: Não aparece um erro exatamente, a busca funciona só que na tela fica aparecendo o código "$&{ }" Eu não entendi por que criaram um input comentado seguido de outro input (o que me aparece o erro em questão) e um terceiro na sequência (que é oque funciona de fato) recebi este código e estou implementando em nosso site mas não entendi o por que foi montado desta forma

Comment: Entendi, isso está errado, simplesmente apaga esse comando $&, pois ele deveria estar em uma tag <script> e não diretamente no html como aí está.

Comment: Vou remover e ver se as funcionalidades se mantém corretas! Também achei que estava errado mas não ia remover sem a certeza de ser um erro. Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

`$&` referencia a função `String.replace()` do JavaScript.

Simplesmente quer dizer que o replace deve ser feito em todo o texto corrente.

Eis um exemplo simples utilizando `$&`:

```
if (typeof String.prototype.highlight !== 'function') {
    String.prototype.highlight = function (match, spanClass) {
        var pattern = new RegExp(match, "gi"),
            highlight = "<span>$&</span>";

        return this.replace(pattern, highlight);
    }
}
```

Setei um [JSFiddle com outro exemplo simples](http://jsfiddle.net/felipekm/WpSz3/1/)

Eis o código do jsfiddle:

```
var value = "My number is 212-555-1234.";
var pattern = new RegExp( "(\\d+)", "g" );

var result = value.replace(
    pattern,
    "[$&]"
);

alert( result );
```

Espero que ajude.